# Convert yyyy-mm-dd to UTC in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time, utc

I need to convert a date in yyyy-mm-dd like 2011-12-30 to UTC using only javascript. How?

Comment: without a timezone, you don't have a date.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var utc = new Date('2011-12-30').toUTCString();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/eun5p/).

Comment: When i run this code in console, or in the jsFiddle link i get a retur of undefined. When i try to access the variable utc. i get "Invalid Date". Am i missing something?

Comment: @Schneems Weird, I get `Thu, 29 Dec 2011 14:00:00 GMT`.

Comment: Hmm...what browser are you using? got this error in safari and firefox -> http://yfrog.com/h0pdo5j

Comment: Yep, works for me in chrome. Can't wait till other browsers catch up. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you're having problems getting the other listed solution to work in firefox or safari you can use: http://www.datejs.com/

```
myDate = new Date.parse("2011-12-30")
myUTCDate = Date.UTC(myDate.getFullYear(), myDate.getMonth(), myDate.getDate(), myDate.getHours(), myDate.getMinutes(), myDate.getSeconds(), myDate.getMilliseconds());
```

Voila!!

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple method to convert String to Date in JavaScript

```
var msomtDate = Date.parse('Here Your Date String'+' UTC',"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var toUTC = function (date) {
    var newDate = new Date();
    newDate.setTime(date.getTime() + (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000));
    return newDate;
};

console.log(toUTC(new Date('2011-12-30')));
```