# Convert Array Data into DateTime Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have one array which contain date.
now i want to convert this value into specify format.
because i receive error **conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value c#** 
here is code

```
                checkedvalue = [];
                $("input[name=chkRoles]").each(function () {

                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

                        checkedvalue.push($(this).val());
                        //alert($(this).val());
                    }

                });
```

theCheckedValue array contain date in format

```
2020-02-12,2020-02-13
```

i want data in format something like this.

```
format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM")
```

Here is my loop code

```
jQuery.each(checkedvalue, function (i, val) {
alert(val);
});
```

In loop i want to convert the format from `2020-02-12` to `2020-02-12 00:00:00.000`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert yyyy-mm-dd to UTC in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273318/convert-yyyy-mm-dd-to-utc-in-javascript)

Comment: `  var userDate = val;
                    var date_string = moment(userDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM");
                    alert(date_string);` Done